# Как установить и запустить phalcon на ubuntu используя terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, phalcon

Всем день добрый. Только начинаю знакомство с Phalkon, подскажите пожалуйста как установить и запустить Phalcon на ubuntu используя terminal?

P.S.: Доки читал - https://phalconphp.com/ru/download, не помогает.

Есть ли у Phalcon аналог команд, как эти для symfony:

скачать и установить -  `composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition name_project`

выполняешь в `/var/www/test_symfony`

запустить - `php bin/console ser:run`

Comment: Я думаю стоит почитать ещё раз, по наитию ни чего просто так не установишь...

Comment: @Naumov Буду читать)) Если у знатоки поделятся опытом, буду признателен.

Comment: Что именно не получается? `не помогает.` слишком размыто

Comment: @UserName Хочу установить и запустить новый проект, запустить через терминал, извините за долгий ответ

Comment: Вы так и не ответили, что именно у Вас не получилось.Т.е на каком этапе возникают проблемы, какого рода эти проблемы.
`Phalcon` представлен в виде `PHP` расширения. Для установки надо: (`1` - Подключить репозиторий через который идет распостранение. `2`  - После подключения репозитория - установить расширение.) или (компилировать из исходников).

Comment: @UserName извините за долгие ответы, я остался временно без ноута. Не получилось написать (для начала) "Hello World" on Phalcon, т.к. не смог его установить, пробовал это делать по аналогии с symfony , laravel

Comment: если не понятно что делать после установки, то вот  http://docs.phalconphp.ru/ru/latest/reference/tools.html, `phalcon create-project name` как и в других, только нужно дополнительно поставить devtools